# deleting a row out of table view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I am having trouble with my `tableView` crashing when I try and delete a row out of the table View. The method gets called correctly as the change is made in the database correctly. The error which I receive is:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];


    NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [fixedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [context deleteObject:objectToDelete];

    [delegate saveContext];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    fixedArray = ([self mondayData]); // this is fetching the data for the array that I supply to the table view

[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[fixedArray count]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [fixedArray count];
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: I have updated the original post to display the number of rows in section method and to display my attempt at returning the correct amount of rows after the edit but unfortunately the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method is likely not returning the appropriate number of rows. It should return the previous number of rows minus the number of rows that have just been deleted.

Also, if there are no more rows in the section, you must delete that section from the UITableView.

Comment: I have updated the original post to display the number of rows in section method and to display my attempt at returning the correct amount of rows after the edit but unfortunately the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
```

and

```
[tableView endUpdates];
```

in your code. These two methods will prevent the `UITableView` from crashing while you delete or insert rows.

Put `beginUpdates`  before you delete the tableView's row, and then `endUpdates` once you're all done.

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates).

Comment: Still the same issue. I think my implementation may have had a number of problems and your answer was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


        NSManagedObject *object = [fixedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [object setValue:@"No" forKey:@"selected"]; // this works and persists into the database

        [delegate saveContext];

        fixedArray = ([self mondayData]);

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    }


    [tableView endUpdates];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

This worked for me in the end.